# Why was Array.prototype.forEach designed to skip undefined values?

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined

[The doc of Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) says:

forEach executes the provided callback once for each element of the array with an assigned value.
It is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have been initialized to undefined.

Why?

Comment: because it does not know what to do with undefined values

Answer (score 3):

Look at this console "experiment" I ran:

[image: Firebug console]

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb5d8.png)

You can clearly see that Array.forEach **does not** skip `undefined` *values* (that the key here). Only `undefined` as in deleted will be skipped.

Comment: **`Array.prototype.forEach` will not skip indexes where value defined as `undefined` (e.g. `array[2] = undefined;`).**

But a value of an indexes equals to `undefined` could be skipped.
Where `var array = new Array(3);`, `array.length == 3 && array[1] === undefined`, but try `array.forEach(function(value, index){console.log(index + ": " + value)})` will output nothing. Where `array = [undefined, undefined, undefined]` will...

Comment: A real WTF moment for me was realizing that `arr[index] = undefined` behaves differently than multiple assignment such as `arr = [,,,]`.  In the first case forEach does not skip undefined, but in the second case it does.

Answer (score 0):

In all browsers except Mozilla Firefox, the forEach function skips elements in the array that have a value of undefined. The function skips unassigned elements in all browsers.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397509.aspx